# Looking to replacing rusty basement ceiling beams

Tags: repair, concrete, beam, water-damage

I have a basement of 9 feet high and on it is my driveway. I had significant water leaks and then discovered that the metal beams of the basement ceiling are all super rusty. I want to resurface my driveway but my contractor did not accept because of the rusty beams. My question is: Can I add new beams and maybe angle them in between the rusty beams?  Can I leave the rusty beams in?

[image]

Comment: You should supply pictures.    Rust to the point of a failed load is pretty extreme.    It can happen but I have seen it maybe once in a lot of years.    Your I Beam having surface rust is not a safety issue.   We can tell better after seeing it.

Comment: Use a pointy tool, and poke in the beam, how far does it goes. Or use a nail and try to nail it in.

Comment: Here is a picture

Comment: The beams are really rusty and some parts can be broken by hand and to resurface the driveway 1.5-2 tons of concrete needs to be added but I am scared the beams will not be able to support that load.

Comment: Wow, you really need an engineer's review on that.  "Super rusty" isn't necessarily a problem if it's surface rust.  You can't really judge by looks.  Might just need good paint (like: power wirebrush + Rustoleum 7769 + alkyd topcoat + run a humidifier down there in the future.  I would not drive an asphalt machine over that, but then, I wouldn't use asphalt either. That should be poured concrete.

Comment: Also, anyone knows what is the name of these beams ?

Comment: I would call it a metal truss.

Comment: If I add beams in between the rusted beams is there a cross-contamination issue? Also, would it support correctly or the rusty beams should be replaced by new ones (the worst option for me financially and too much work)

Comment: In particular, what you're looking at is an open web steel K-joist

Comment: Beam looks bent [at the weak-point where the reinforcing changes design] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je9Vv.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this requires the expertise of someone on site. We can't tell from one distant picture how much damage there is, what the load it, what the design load needs to be, or any of the other myriad details necessary to ensure this remains safe.

Answer (score 0):

For one, do not drive the car over that drive way.

Get professionals to knock out the old drive way.

Then using the rebar construction pore new driveway which becomes your new ceiling.

Demolish the old rusty ceiling.

Now you are good for long time, no more rust.

Comment: will the rebar in the concrete be enough to hold the driveway? Also, to demolish the rusty rebars it is going to cost a fortune no ? Can't I just add new beams in between the rusty ones and pour the concrete over it ?

Comment: OK, you have driven in Garages on second or x Floor. They have concrete floor/ceilings. So yes it will work. You can leave the. rusty stuff in place, it serves no purpose any more, and just cover it with something of your choice, or just leave it..

Comment: Do you want to do it your self ?? I would not recommend it. Too much structural danger. What was there first, the basement with metal roof, or the drive way with basement dug under it?

Comment: I have a contractor that will do the work but he gave me the option of adding more beams in between the rusty beams and is waiting for my answer .. I was not sure if it is acceptable to leave rusted beams in .. or if the addition of the beams will still support the load even if it is not located at the initial placement of the beams.

Comment: "will the rebar in the concrete be enough to hold the driveway".  No, not without structural supports (like the metal trusses shown) under the slab.  If you don't provide that support, then you need the slab to be a pre-stressed construction that can withstand the tension/bending forces that will result when you drive a vehicle on the driveway.  I don't think that a typical poured garage kind of slab will cut it.  You need some expertise here.